# Convert list of objects to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, object, nested

I have list of JSON objects that has lists and dictionaries inside. I would like to create columns for each leave property at each level and create a Pandas dataframe. I played for few hours and came up with a primitive approach.

---

My initial JSON objects looks as follows:

```
[
{
    "first_seq": 3329651855,
    "out": {
        "flags": "S",
        "first_window_size": 29200,
        "opt_len": 20,
        "opts": [
            {
                "mss": 1460
            },
            {
                "sackp": null
            },
            {
                "ts": {
                    "val": 1211987020,
                    "ecr": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "noop": null
            },
            {
                "ws": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    "in": {
        "flags": "SA",
        "first_window_size": 26847,
        "opt_len": 20,
        "opts": [
            {
                "mss": 1460
            },
            {
                "sackp": null
            },
            {
                "ts": {
                    "val": 3518874230,
                    "ecr": 1211987020
                }
            },
            {
                "noop": null
            },
            {
                "ws": 7
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "first_seq": 3329651855,
    "out": {
        "flags": "S",
        "first_window_size": 29200,
        "opt_len": 20,
        "opts": [
            {
                "mss": 1460
            },
            {
                "sackp": null
            },
            {
                "ts": {
                    "val": 1211987020,
                    "ecr": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "noop": null
            },
            {
                "ws": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    "in": {
        "flags": "SA",
        "first_window_size": 26847,
        "opt_len": 20,
        "opts": [
            {
                "mss": 1460
            },
            {
                "sackp": null
            },
            {
                "ts": {
                    "val": 3518874230,
                    "ecr": 1211987020
                }
            },
            {
                "noop": null
            },
            {
                "ws": 7
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

I want to create following columns:

- first_sequence
- out_flag
- out_window_size
- out_opts_mss
- out_opts_sackp
- out_opts_ts_val
- in_flag
- in_window_size
- in_opts_mss
- in_opts_sackp
- in_opts_ts_val

---

I believe there's a simple way of achieving this instead instead duplicating codes. Appreciate your help in writing an efficient Python function (recursive or any) to achieve this.

Comment: Load your json object using `json.loads`. After loading it should be list of nested dictionaries. Convert each of this dictionaries to one level dictionary and then build a DataFrame from list of converted dictionaries using `pd.Dataframe(converted_list)`

Answer (score 0):

**First thing you have to convert your json to csv:-**

[**Here you can convert your json to csv easily**](https://konklone.io/json/)

After converting to csv you can easily load your file to pandas.